# Warp a 2D image onto another image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have obtained a 3D wavefront model of face inside a portrait and then that face is transformed using mesh_numpy and a 2D transformed image is saved. As the images are attached. Now I want to warp this transformed image back onto the original image. It's like face swap where I have both source and target image. What is the better way to achieve it.

Original:

[image]

Transformed:

[image]

Comment: do you have "control points"/"landmarks"/"key points" detected on the face in the image? can you establish correspondences between the face in the image and the wrapped face?

Comment: I have landmarks of the original image, obtained it using DLib. How do I form a correspondence between warped and original? Do I have to find landmarks for the transformed face as well and then find a mapping?

Comment: you should have similar landmarks on the 3D model and hence on the wrapped face as well. Use these corresponding landmarks to map the face back to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: If anyone faces this issue in near future, I managed to achieve this by using Homography.